# Is btrfs balance recursive?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, fedora, filesystems, btrfs

I run [`btrfs balance`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-balance.html) on a daily basis thanks to a systemd service+timer to try to keep my filesystem healthy over time (is it even a good idea?). The command I use is as follow:

```
btrfs balance start -dusage=50 -dlimit=2 -musage=50 -mlimit=4 /
```

I have many subvolumes mounted to different locations:

- @root is mounted to /
- @home is mounted to /home
- @var is mounted to /var
- @var-log is mounted to /var/log
- @snapshots is mounted to /.snapshots
- @swap is mounted to /.swap

And many more.

I'm wondering if my btrfs balance command goes through all the subvolumes by passing `/` to it or if I should run the command for every single subvolume I have.

The snapshot command would not recurse into subvolumes, but what about the balance operation ?

Comment: In the manual page you linked to, the word "subvolume" does not appear at all, "filesystem" is used many times. This looks like a clue to me.

Comment: Indeed, nice catch, thanks. Though for such a "critical" component of my system I was hoping for a more obvious answer